# Fuerteventura surfing and quiet romantic accommodation

Tags: accommodation, surfing, romance, canary-islands

My partner and I are looking to go surfing in Fuerteventura in November and we're looking for recommendations for a surf school and accommodation.

We'd like to be able to sit in the evenings, listen to the sounds of the sea and watch the sunset. Not after luxury but something characterful and quiet within a short taxi trip or walk of some decent restaurants and not completely empty bars. It would be great if the hotel/b&b/yurt could offer help with other activities - such as diving or walking.

We'd like to surf but maybe not every day and would need to hire everything. Would be good if transport was included or an option.

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for late answer. Hope this will help you somehow in future.

First of all, review the [official site](http://www.fuerteventura.com/) and [forum](http://www.fuerteventura-forum.com/) for the island.
Off. site has an [article about surfing](http://www.fuerteventura.com/surfing/index.shtml):

> As with windsurfing, Fuerteventura has become a Mecca for surfers and
>   boogyboarders especially during the Autmn/winter months with the
>   advent of the large Atlantic swells.
>   **The Surf on Fuerteventura**
>   The most consistent surf is found on the **north/NW coast** with many spots 'unridden'. There are waves to suit
>   most standards of surfers but also some absolute gems for the more
>   adventurous.   The surf is pretty much divided into two main seasons -
>   Autumn/Winter and Spring/Summer - much along the lines of the rest of
>   Northern Europe.   There are perfect breaks to suit all abilities and
>   some top class surf schools for the total beginner.

[image]

According naming, **Suicides** is my favorite (just kidding). So, I think, all surfers will be at the north side of island, and I suggest you to book hotel there. There are [surfing school with accomodation there](http://billabongsurfcamp.com/accommodation/), and it is [near the mainstream places](http://billabongsurfcamp.com/contact/) for surfing.

They have all [needed stuff for rent](http://billabongsurfcamp.com/surf-pack/surfboards-and-wetsuits-rentals/), and they even have some [Surfaris](http://billabongsurfcamp.com/surf-pack/surfaris/) option, I think this is what you need.

Official site is a place you can search for other activities and find rental company. Users from there are recommending TopCar.

PS: visit [Betancuria](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Betancuria&hl=ru&safe=off&tbo=u&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ei=f1zIUO-NLYXb4QTFyYBY&ved=0CDAQsAQ&biw=1270&bih=900) - it's beautiful:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. We decided to go to Sri Lanka in the end and returned to a lovely spot at Tallala Retreat at the south of the island. Great for beginners and Jack is a super coach. Fuerteventura next time I think. Thanks again.

Comment: Great answer! going there next week! Thank you for the detailed advice =0)